# Having difficulty locating an element using ID, XPATH and CSS

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Unable to locate an anchor element present inside an li element using Selenium webdriver.

For the below HTML DOM structure, I am unable to locate the second li element. I basically want to locate it and perform click operation on it there by loading in a new page using Selenium Webdriver.

Tried to access it using the below methods:

```
id - docTab

xpath -.//div[@class='secondary-tabs']/ul/li[1]/a

xpath - //*[@id="docTab"]

xpath - /html/body/div[1]/main/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/ul/li[2]/a

css - #docTab. tab__heading

css - li[id="docTab"]
```

But all of it are resulting in "Unable to locate element" error. This is happening even after including driver.wait methods.

**DOM Structure:**

```
<div class="secondary-tabs">
 <ul class="tabs tabs--bordered">
    <li class="tab active second_tabs" id="textTab" tabdivid="textSecond"><a><div class="tab__heading" title="Text">Text</div></a></li>
    <li class="tab second_tabs" id="docTab" tabdivid="docSecond"><a><div class="tab__heading" title="File">Document</div></a></li>
    <li class="tab second_tabs" id="faqTab" tabdivid="faqSecond"><a><div class="tab__heading" title="FAQ" onclick="FAQ">FAQ</div></a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

I expect to locate the second li element and perform click event on it using selenium web driver.

Comment: Is the page fully loaded when your code executes?

Comment: Which client are you using? Java, Python, C#?

Comment: Page is fully loaded. I am using Java.

Comment: Navigate to the page in Chrome and open the devtools. Run `$$("#docTab")`... how many elements are returned? My guess is you need a wait or your element is in an IFRAME.

Comment: Hi JeffC, I ran the command and it is returning [li#docTab.tab.second_tabs]. Is this the CSS selector to be used?

Answer (score 1):

To `click()` on the element with text as **Document** you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following solutions:

- *Java*:

  - *cssSelector*:

    ```
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div.secondary-tabs>ul li#docTab[tabdivid='docSecond']"))).click();
    ```
  - *xpath*:

    ```
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='secondary-tabs']/ul//li[@id='docTab' and @tabdivid='docSecond']"))).click();
    ```

Answer (score -1):

You can try below given selector.

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='secondarytabs']//child::ul//child::li[@id='docTab' and tabdivid='docSecond']"))).click();
```